# Why does comparison of NAN return true?

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754

As written in Java Language Specification 'The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= return false if either or both operands are NaN'
So I was comparing two NAN's.
Why does it print true in the console when I compare two NAN?

```
double f = 3/0.0d;
double h = 2/0.0d;
        
System.out.println((f>=h));
```

f and h are both NAN and when i compared them i expected to print false but i got true as my output.

Comment: Because the values of `f` and `h` are _not_ `NaN`, but rather `infinity`! `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` is `false`, but `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is `true`.

Comment: ur code in jshell: https://i.imgur.com/GSEzozX.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.0/0 doesn't produce NaN:

```
System.out.println(2.0/0.0);
> Infinity
```

There are 3 'non-numeric' values of doubles:

- Positive infinity
- Negative infinity
- NaN

As per spec, positiveinfinity is equal to positive infinity, and negative infinity is equal to negative infinity. Only NaN isn't equal to itself.

we can get NaN:

```
double nan = 0.0 / 0.0;
System.out.println(nan);
System.out.println(nan == nan);
> NaN
> false
```

If you actually need NaN somewhere (e.g. you want to return it), the most legible way to get there is `Double.NaN`. The above example simply shows how one might get a NaN value out of a calculation naturally - when zero is divided by zero is the most common way. A few other ways:

```
double posInf = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
double negInf = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
System.out.println(posInf - posInf); // NaN
System.out.println(posInf - negInf); // positive infinity
System.out.println(posInf / posInf); // NaN
```

Comment: Consider "there are 3 'non-numeric' values" better as "there are 3 'non-finite' values".

Comment: That's more an issue for philosophy. Infinity isn't numeric, that's clear as day: They do not consist of numbers and do not represent a single value (hence, why 'positive infinity minus positive infinity' isn't zero, but NaN - because they represent a cloud of numbers). I'd go so far as: Non-Numeric is in fact a better term (and NaN is a bad term).

Comment: Disagree about "that's clear as day" as viewing infinity as numeric has much rational including: 0.0/0.0 is also NAN, yet that does not make 0.0 non-numeric.  Infinity >= all other numeric, infinity + infinity --> infinity, 1/infinity --> 0.0, ... and many other uses of infinity lend to viewing it as numeric.  Infinity is numerical ordered when using `unordered(x, y)`.  As infinity is not a _not-a-number_, it is lexicographically a _number_.  Java treat infinity as a number with infinite value.

Comment: It's a shades of gray situation: Infinity behaves partly numerically, and partly non-numerically. I stand by this answer. In this case, extracting a overly specific interpretation (as in, more specific than your average listener/reader would intuit) to the word 'Number' off of the notion that NaN is short for not-a-number is not a fair logical jump: NaN has 60 years of historical baggage as a term.

Answer (score 2):

[Rogue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946812/why-does-comparison-of-nan-return-true#comment135646791_76946812)
 has already explained it nicely:

> Because the values of `f` and `h` are not `NaN`, but rather infinity!
> `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` is `false`, but `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` is `true`.

In addition to this comment, you should know that `NaN` indicates the result of an invalid operation e.g. `0/0.0d`, `Math.sqrt(-1)` etc. So, the following statement will print `false`:

```
System.out.println(0 / 0.0d == Math.sqrt(-1));
```

Answer (score -1):

> *"... Why does it print true in the console when I compare two NAN? ..."*

They're not *NaN*.

```
f = Infinity
h = Infinity
```

The *[Double](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html)* class has a *[NaN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#NaN)* field which uses the following.

```java
public static final double NaN = 0.0d / 0.0;
```

Output

```
false
```